# I cannot run a Sublime Text 3 Python program from Command Prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, windows-10

I am going through the Python Crash Course book 2nd Edition and trying to set up Sublime Text 3 programs to run from a terminal. I have made sure Sublime Text is running Python and have saved a simple Print("Hello) program to a file called python_work. Now I try and run the program from Command Prompt,
I enter **cd Desktop\python_work** and I get the answer **The system cannot find the path specified.**
The command prompt should show **\Desktop\python_work>** and I would contiune from there.
Why do I get this message and how can I fix it? (I am using Windows 10)

Comment: `python_work` is a file. `cd` moves you to the *directory* specified. Use `cd Desktop`.

Comment: Your question isn't really related to Sublime Text at all if you're just using it to create your file but trying to run your program manually in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting **The system cannot find the path specified** because *the location of the python_work folder was not directly located on my desktop*, the location was C:\User\Me\OneDrive\Desktop. I either had to move the file directly to my desktop or use the command **cd OneDrive\Desktop\python_work**. So if you get **The system cannot find the path specified** go to properties on your folder and check the exact location and try inputting that into command prompt.